# Not able to login in site using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I tried a lot and tired now :(

I need to Load test a Website. I have configured all things, specified all necessary extractor & expressions and try to login, but it is giving me **Response code: 302**. I can see that **GET LOGIN & POST LOGIN** requests working perfect but page which is coming just after login is getting 302 in JMeter.

Then, I have recorded a script using proxy to verify that if I am passing all values and expressions correctly or not , and found that I am doing it right.

Now what could be reason of not able to login when try to perform without record. I have read all type of solutions from internet but still there is not success.

**SOLVED BY FOLLOWING :**

1 - Add Cookie manager

2 - Set CookieManager.save.cookies=true in jmeter.properties. By default it was false.

Comment: Have you added the Cookie Manager in your script and specified the cookies in it?

Comment: Yes I have added cookie manager but what to specify in it?

Comment: You should specify the value of the Cookies being used in your application, without cookies you will not be able to maintain session and no page after login will be shown. You can see the used cookies in Tree Listener or in Developers Toolbar or Fiddler etc. Also, are you able to login with the recorded script? Is your recorded script working fine?

Comment: Yes with proxy recording it is working fine. also I am getting [no cookies] in  listener?  now what to do?

Comment: Then I may need to take a look at the other setting which you have for your manual created scripts, in your HTTP Request. If your recorded script is working fine, then there might be some issue with your created script, some checkbox or some missing request. Also, I will suggest to use the recorded script as it is working fine and it will too provide you the same results which you need for the load test.

Comment: Another way is to create manual script from the recorded script and see if it is working fine i.e. Add HTTP Request manually but copy the parameters, URL etc. from the recorded HTTP Request samplers and then run your manual created script. If that works then you will know what you have missed in your original script.

Comment: I did exactly that but no luck. Let me check everything again. Will back to you if issue persist.

Comment: Hey it is solved by 2 things : 1 - Add Cookie manager , 2 - Set CookieManager.save.cookies=true in jmeter.properties. Thanks you to you also..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common reasons are:

- missing or incorrect mandatory dynamic parameter. In that case you need to identify it, extract from 1st response via [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and use the extracted value in 2nd request
- missing [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- in case of external authentication (Basic HTTP, NTLM or Kerberos) - missing or improperly configured [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) - see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide for more information on how to bypass external authentication challenge with JMeter.

Comment: Yep , I was passing wrong Regular expression Extractor data. Thank you.. Issue solved :)